# Check if SKAction contains an action (swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to program a little game using swift. I'm translating some old obj-C sprite-kit code and doesn't find how to translate this code. In obj-C a SKACtion has a member called hasActions that tells you if the vars contains an action but in swift seems that theses property doesn't exists and also there isn't a method to do the same action.

Original obj-C code :

```
SKAction *animAction = [self.player actionForKey:animationKey];

    // If this animation is already running or there are no frames we exit
    if ( animAction || animationFrames.count < 1 )
    {
        return;
    }
```

Swift code

```
var animAction : SKAction = player.actionForKey(animationKey)!

// If this animation is already running or there are no frames we exit
if animAction || animationFrames.count < 1
{
    return
}
```

variable `animationFrames.count` is an array and doesn't throw any error.
The exact error is 'Type 'SkAction doesn't conform to protocol BooleanType'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write

> var animAction : SKAction! = player.actionForKey(animationKey)
>
> if animAction != nil || animationFrames.count < 1 {
>
> ```
> return
> ```
>
> }

The error was on **animAction**, not animationFrames.

For the hasActions, it is still there in Swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/hasActions

> var node = SKNode()
>
> node.hasActions()

Comment: `animAction` needs to be an optional type to check it against `nil`. You want to check `if animAction != nil ...`

Comment: I edited the == to !=, sorry about that. A variable does not have to be optional to check it against nil.

Comment: A variable can't be `nil` unless it is an optional.

Comment: `let toto:Int! = nil

if toto == nil {
    println("true")
}`

Try this in your playground.

Comment: Yes. `toto` is an implicitly unwrapped optional. That IS an optional. The original poster’s `animAction` is not an optional.

Comment: I thought the SKAction was an implicitly unwrapped optional. I edited the code to add it. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to remove the last ! because the original code was unwrapping the optional, and that will crash if nil.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Swift 2.x** you can easily do:

```
public extension SKNode {
    public func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
        return self.actionForKey(key) != nil ? true : false
    }
}
```

And you can write for example:

```
var myHero: SKSpriteNode!
...
if myHero.actionForKeyIsRunning("moveLeft") {
   // my character moving to the left
   print("moving to the left")
}
```